# SQL DTS conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server

It's me again, i have a output from a Microsoft SQL Server (via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio) like this 20200820112518RS
I'm trying to convert this to a usefull date like dd-MM-yyyy hh:MM:ss but everything i try gives an error.
What works:

`CAST(DTS as varchar(14))` gives me `20200820112518`
`CAST(DTS as datetime)` gives an error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

`CONVERT(carchar(14),DTS,120)` gives me `20200820112518`
`CONVERT(varchar,(CAST(DTS as varchar(14))),121)` gives me the same

Comment: The error is telling you the problem `'20200820112518RS'` is clearly not a valid date and time value. What date and time *is* it meant to be? I *assume* `2020-08-20T11:25:18` but what does the RS represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling you the problem `'20200820112518RS'` is clearly not a valid date and time value.

I *assume* that the `20200820112518` portion represents the date, so what you need to do is format that into an ISO format; specifically `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss`. One method is to inject the characters with `STUFF`, though this gets messy as you need so many:

```sql
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(LEFT(V.DTS,14),13,0,':'),11,0,':'),9,0,'T'),7,0,'-'),5,0,'-'))
FROM (VALUES('20200820112518RS'))V(DTS)
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu, i was hoping to get something else because, as you said, this is very messy when you insert this into a query. :-/
For the moment I did the same in the result export (in Excel).
Thanks you anyway :-)